# jeditable on div element in iframe

Tags: iframe, html, jeditable

I am dynamically creating an iframe and loading it with content from a cgi. The content is a table. I would like to apply jeditable to a div in that iframe content. Here is the html which renders as I need.

```
<td align=left width=5%><font style="font-family:lucida console; font-size: 10px;"><div class="edit" id="div_1">$databasename</div><div class="edit_area" id="div_2"></div>
```

and here is the js:

```
            var iframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');
            $(iframe).attr({
                    id: 'frameName',
                    frameBorder: 'none',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '465',
                    scrolling: 'yes',
                    src: "./dump.cgi?system=" + sys
            });

            document.body.appendChild(iframe);

            $(iframe).load(function() {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                            $('.edit').editable('./adtu.php', {
                                    indicator : 'Saving...',
                                    tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
                            });
                            $('.edit_area').editable('./adtu.php', {
                                    type      : 'textarea',
                                    cancel    : 'Cancel',
                                    submit    : 'OK',
                                    indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
                                    tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
                            });
                    });
            });
```

The jquery.js and jquery.jeditable.js ARE NOT coded in the cgi. I'm hoping to avoid that overhead, but I will try if advised.

So when the page loads I click on the "databasename" in the table and I get nothing. I have had the jeditable code in numerous places. This code is my latest attempt, my thinking being that the iframe was not ready for jeditable to find the div class when coded outside the load() function.

I would lose the cgi and frame altogether but the cgi has other submit functions and the iframe container is how I contain the page refresh.

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: I ended up adding the SCRIPT calls to the cgi script and I can get jeditable to work. I'm using perl and CGI.pm. Here's how I included the js. The je.js file contains the document read code: 

print $arcstat->start_html(-title=>"Object Control",
-script=>[
        { -type => 'text/javascript',
          -src => '../jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js'
        },
        { -type => 'text/javascript',
          -src => '../jquery/jquery.jeditable.js'
        },
        { -type => 'text/javascript',
          -src => './je.js'
        },
        ]
);

Wish there was a better "jQuery" way